# Are users more likely to capitalize their names in name input fields?

Tags: forms, input, input-fields, names

I have a registration form where users are required to provide their first and last name. I've been contemplating implementing some sort of auto-capitalization callback but after reading this [post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/26560/auto-capitalization-of-name-input-fields) I decided not to go through with it. I only wonder now if users are naturally inclined to capitalize their name given the additional effort in having to `shift + click` vs. quickly getting the registration process over using lowercase format.

Answer (score 6):

In any population, there will always be some outliers who don't do things the way most of the population does. Someone, surely, will fail to capitalize their name.

**What's the drawback**, if users don't capitalize their own name?

Do these names get used in a context where it might reflect poorly on the company? Do the names get used in legal documents or on ID cards, and such?

If so, in a case where there's capitalization you don't expect, why don't you prompt the user once, and give them a good reason to get it right? For example:

> This name will appear in [this important document or place]. Please ensure your name is capitalized correctly.
>
> [image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 but I never Shift + Key; not even with I see that. But that's just me.

Comment: Drawbacks of users entering bad data: occasional bad data.  Drawbacks of "fixing" users' input for them: algorithmic errors that introduce bad data and simultaneously gives users around the world an unpleasant experience with your product.

Comment: @dimo414 So its really a lose-lose but for the greater good in regards to a well balanced UX?

Comment: @CarlEdwards I wouldn't go that far.  You can't ever ensure users will always input data the way you want, but you can be sure your users will hate it if you change what they input.  The former is just a fact of life, the latter is bad UX.